# What is default font for elements in html if no font is set in css

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I want know what is the default font for elements in a html document.
for example if i use this jquery code :
`var elemfont = jQuery('.elem').css('font-family');`
What it returns if there is no font defined in css ?
And what returns if its parent has a font ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers have `serif` as the default `font-family` when one is not specified. `serif` resolves to Times or Times New Roman, depending on your operating system, etc.

If you call `$(document.body).css("font-family")` where a font is not set on the body or a parent element, jQuery will not give you `serif`, but resolve the browser's default font name and give you that. On Windows, on Chrome, FF, or IE, you'd get `"Times New Roman"`.

Comment: Thank you . so it dont returns empty string (or null) at all ?

Comment: jQuery always returns a non-empty string. If you access ```document.body.style.fontFamily```, for exmaple, you'll get ```""```, not null or udefined.

Answer (score 3):

The default font depends on the browser and on the element. Most browsers have a default font that they apply to the `body` element, and it gets inherited by inner elements when nothing intervenes, but browsers also have special default fonts set e.g. for `input` and `select` elements. Moreover, if an element contains characters that are not present in the browser’s default font, the browser is expected to scan through fonts in the system to find one that has got it.

What `jQuery('.elem').css('font-family')` returns is really a different question, and should have been asked separately and tagged as a jquery question. However, the answer is rather simple: according to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/), `.css(font-family)` returns the computed value of `font-family` for the first element in the set of matched elements. In the absence of any CSS settings, this will be the specific font family used as the browser’s default font. As mentioned above, this does not guarantee that all (or any!) characters in the element will be displayed in that font—only that the browser will *first* check that font when finding fonts for characters.